# Trying to send push notification only when post from selected category

Tags: wordpress, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to send push notifications through Wordpress plugin only when I post from given category. But it's not working.

/* Handle notification when add new post*/

```
function fcm_main_transition_post_new($new_status, $old_status, $post){
    $catId = get_cat_ID();
    if( $catId == 'Result'){
        fcm_notif_post_new($new_status, $old_status, $post);
    }
    else{
        echo "This category is not set to send push notification.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually `$post` variable? If it's [from WordPress core](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post), use this code:

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    if( $category->cat_ID == 'Your category ID' ){
        // Send notification please
    }

    // If you need category slug check
    if( $category->cat_name == 'Your category slug' ){
        // Send notification please
    }
}
```

And `get_cat_ID()` return an integer, not string like `Result`.

Comment: Yes, $post is from core. This is not working. I tried using category id i.e. 1 at "Category name" but still it didn't work.

Comment: OMG I made a mistake, `$categories` is an array. So please checkout my edited answer for working code.